# SQL: count rows from 3rd table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, the first table is the `account_has_account1` where i store the relation between accounts and it's columns are `account_id, account_id1, status` where `account_id` is the account doing following to `account_id1` and `status` is an enum type with values `active, inactive` where `active` indicates if the account is actually following, if it's inactive, then account stopped following.

the second table is named `account_has_photos` which i store the photos one account has stored in the database, so it's columns are `account_id, photos_id`, so i need this table to get all photos from one account which another account is following.

But all these have messages posted on them, and here is where the 3rd table comes which is named `photos_has_message_photos`, from this table i only need a count of all posted messages in one photo, the columns are `photos_id, message_photos_id`

for now my query is this:

```
SELECT account_has_photos.photos_id as id, "photos" as type, account_has_photos.update_at, account_has_photos.account_id
FROM account_has_account1 
    JOIN account_has_photos 
        ON (account_has_photos.account_id = account_has_account1.account_id1 AND account_has_photos.type_id = 17)
WHERE account_has_account1.account_id = 7 AND account_has_account1.`status` = "Active"
```

it shows all photos from accounts on which account id 7 is following, but on my attempts on getting the total messages have failed, i thought on doing an `INNER JOIN` like this:

```
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT photos_has_message_photos.photos_id, count(photos_has_message_photos.photos_id) as total
        FROM photos_has_message_photos
    ) posts
        ON(posts.photos_id = account_has_photos.photos_id)
```

and then i select from main `posts.total`, but it does not show any row, not even the photos, the result is empty at this point and i have no idea why and what to do.

the complete query is like this:

```
SELECT account_has_photos.photos_id as id, "photos" as type, account_has_photos.update_at, account_has_photos.account_id, posts.total
FROM account_has_account1 
    JOIN account_has_photos 
        ON (account_has_photos.account_id = account_has_account1.account_id1 AND account_has_photos.type_id = 17)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT photos_has_message_photos.photos_id, count(photos_has_message_photos.photos_id) as total
        FROM photos_has_message_photos
    ) posts
        ON(posts.photos_id = account_has_photos.photos_id)
WHERE account_has_account1.account_id = 7 AND account_has_account1.`status` = "Active"
```

again, i only need a total of rows which are messages from each photos found

Comment: Tip of the day: table aliases!

Comment: And you know that `JOIN` is just short form of `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: What?!? How can MySQL figure out what kind of join the user wants?

Comment: @jarlh i had my doubts and i searched it. you are right, they are equal, the explanation given to me was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query updated inner select

```
 SELECT ahp.photos_id as id, "photos" as type, ahp.update_at, ahp.account_id,posts.total
FROM account_has_account1 
    JOIN account_has_photos 
        ON (ahp.account_id = account_has_account1.account_id1 AND ahp.type_id = 17) INNER JOIN (
        SELECT phmp.photos_id, count(*) as total FROM photos_has_message_photos GROUP BY phmp.photos_id
    ) posts
        ON(posts.photos_id = ahp.photos_id) WHERE account_has_account1.account_id = 7 AND account_has_account1.`status` = "Active"
```

Comment: i come to realize now, wouldn't this break if the join finds no data for the count function?.. cause i've been making the same method for other tables and they show nothing when there is no record found, not even showing 0 value for count